encountering USB errors during arch installation "usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71"

I am attempting to install a barebones Arch Linux setup alongside my Windows 11 configuration with the Hyprland desktop environment. However, I am encountering persistent errors during the installation process. Upon booting, the system repeatedly displays the error message 'unable to read user address 31 error -71' until the ISO image is loaded into RAM. Once I access the root environment, the errors resume.
I have tested three different USB drives, which function properly on another laptop but are not recognized on this one. I have installed the latest Arch ISO (10_2024) using both Rufus and Ventoy. The USB drive is prioritized in the BIOS settings, with fast boot, legacy, and secure boot all disabled. I have also tried enabling legacy boot while disabling secure boot, but the issue persists.
Despite using a new USB drive that was detected and ran fine initially, the error spamming begins when the system attempts to load the ISO image. Additionally, I have ensured that there are no faulty devices connected, and both USB ports have been tested.
I seek guidance on resolving this issue, as all other settings appear to be correct, but the installation process continues to fail.

Is there anything connected to a USB Hub? If so disconnect all the items from the Hub and attempt the install without the hub.  After the install plug in the hub with nothing connected.  Looking at Error -71 at  Linux Kernel Error Codes reveals 71 to be a Protocol Error.  If disconnecting the USB Hub solves the problem, provide the model of the hub here.  There may be a better driver available.

See Also the last Question in the Related Questions in the right Sidebar.

I have tried every possible solution given on those forum threads but none work

I don't have a hub its a laptop it has two ports i have tried from both but still no luck and is this a driver issue idk ?

Have you tried turning off the webcam and mic in your Setup Utility as the question in the sidebar suggests? Otherwise can you list the peripherals that are available in your BIOS.  Turn each one off one at a time, until the protocol error disappears, then turn all the others on.  Whatever the last item you toggle off is having a hardware issue, as the sidebar answer suggests.

well I found a way around the installation I put some kernel parameters before the installation for stopping the error spam and then installed the arch but i still get that error IDK why at rebooting I will try that solution too thx a lot for the suggestion

If you get a definitive answer, post it and I will upvote. You can self-accept your own answer after (48 hrs) to gain valuable reputation points.
